# Why can't I add a typescript file to a folder in VS2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am following this tutorial

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html

To make a C# project using typescript and angular 2. The problem is that when I try to add a typescript file to a folder I get this window[image]

which doens't contain the typescrit file option. Instead of this
[image]

How can I get the second window to be displayed, when I try to add an item to a folder?

Comment: Isn't it under the `.NET Core`-directory?

Comment: Yes. You must select .NET Core.

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: yes now it is solved

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Typescript support in Visual Studio. You can get it in
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593